# PayPal Adaptive Payments return URL parameters

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using PayPal Adaptive Payments (a deprecated integration method) with PHP.

When calling the "Pay" request, I always used to set the return URL to:

```
https://my-website/my-return-page.php?payKey=${payKey}
```

Then, when the payment is succesful, PayPal should redirect the user to something like:

```
https://my-website/my-return-page.php?payKey=AP-ABCDEF123456
```

But now, the PayPal API is throwing an error:

```
The URL https://my-website/my-return-page.php?payKey=${payKey} is malformed
```

There was no change in our end, it just stopped working.

I need the payKey in the return URL, so I can check the paymentDetails.

Comment: Doesn't PayPal automatically add its own key values to the return URL?

Comment: Nop, is not added by default (At least not for me). And adding `&payKey=${payKey}` at the end of the URL was working fine for me.

Comment: @PrestonPHX check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397444/1172363

Answer (score 0):

> adding &payKey=${payKey}

Oh, based on the answer [you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397444/1172363) you were sending that actual text as-is and PayPal was dynamically replacing that with the value.

It doesn't seem that syntax is supported anymore; it's not documented.

What I would recommend is generate your own unique ID, and pass that as `?id=abcde12345`. Then when you first get the payKey from the initial Pay API response, associate this payKey with your own id (e.g. abcde12345).  It could be the same as the TrackingID or Invoice ID, if you happen to use either parameter/feature of Adaptive Payments.

Then, the return should have ?id=abcde12345 and you can look up the payKey and proceed from there with paymentDetails.

---

You can also report this change in behavior with Adaptive Payments as a PayPal bug, but since it's a very old and deprecated product that's likely to be sunset at some point, I'm not sure how much traction re-implementing an undocumented feature would have, so the above workaround of your own id seems like a better plan.

Comment: The weird thing is... This thing is only broken on "sandbox" mode (Test site)... when using live mode (Production site), it works again (With exactly the same parameters)... no error comes from Paypal... And i get the payKey in the return URL as expected.

Comment: I have the same issue. Works for live site but not for Sandbox! No code changes either.